# syntax error(missing operator) in query in ms access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

i have the following relational database tables

[image]

to get the author name of a certain book i made the following query

> SELECT authors.name
>
> FROM  authors
>
> INNER JOIN book_author ON  authors.id=book_author.author_id
>
> INNER JOIN books
>
> ON books.id=book_author.book_id  WHERE  books.id=1;

but it is giving me the error in the title .How i can fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name is not a field in the table "authors". Select authors.author_name and it will run.

```
SELECT authors.author_name

FROM authors

INNER JOIN book_author ON authors.id=book_author.author_id
WHERE book_author.book_id=1;
```